# Getting Vehicle's angle in SUMO with Traci4j

Tags: java, angle, omnet++, traffic-simulation

I want to work together with SUMO and OMNeT++ in order to create a VANET simulation. For this purpose, I am using the Traci4j library for Java (available at https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J), which allows to interact with SUMO from a remote port.

First of all I would like to state that I know that Veins exists, but I strongly have the need to do it with Java as part of my Bachelor Tesis

For the moment, I am able to get all the vehicles that are driving across my network, and get their speed and position (X,Y). However, I would also like to get the direction (angle) in which this vehicles are moving.

I have been looking through the different methods contained in Traci4j but I haven't found anything. The only related-part-of-code that I have found is in the class Constants:

```
/** angle (get: vehicle) */
public static final int VAR_ANGLE = 0x43;
```

But I don't really understand what is this useful for. Do you think it is possible to obtain this attribute from the vehicles?

I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle attribute is available via TraCI but the corresponding message is not implemented in TraCI4J. You might want to switch to [TraaS](http://traas.sourceforge.net/cms/) which has this function implemented and is in general considered better in functional coverage of the TraCI protocol. This (untested) snippet might help:

```
 import de.tudresden.sumo.cmd.Vehicle;
 import it.polito.appeal.traci.SumoTraciConnection;

 SumoTraciConnection conn = new SumoTraciConnection(sumo_bin, config_file);
 conn.runServer();

 //load routes and initialize the simulation
 conn.do_timestep();

 double angle = (double) conn.do_job_get(Vehicle.getAngle("v0"));
```

Comment: In this case I would need to have internet connection in my computer?

Comment: No. All the sockets are opened locally.